# How to get the data in SQL Server for string concat value compare to int value without using like operator

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have table with data like this:

```
Id  |  StringValue
----+-------------
1   |    4,50
2   |    90,40
```

I will get input `StringValue` like 4. I need to fetch the data exact matched record. When I am using `LIKE` operator, select query is returning two rows, but I need exact matched data record only.

Can anybody please help me with this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE StringValue like '%4%'
```

But that returns two rows - both ID 1 and 2.

My expectation is I  need to get ID = 1 row only

Comment: I'm not clear your problem yet. In your case, there are two records StringValue = {1=4,50 | 2=90,40}.

`select * from table1 where StringValue like '%4%'` it means value can be some numbers before `4` and some numbers after `4`.

If you want to get number start with `4` you can query `select * from table1 where StringValue like '4%'`

Comment: Even 4% also will have problem. Suppose if the string value is something like '44,8' then 4% will give this record result as well. I want exact matched record

Comment: Can you give more examples and explain what you want? Or you want '4,%'?

Comment: So given the values `4,50` and `90,40` - **WHAT** is the *exact match* you're talking about? Not really clear.... are those **numerical** values - or are those comma-separated strings? Comma-separated is a big no-no anyway.....(violating first normal form of database design)

Answer (score 1):

Storing delimited data like this is a well documented anti-pattern, violates basic normalisation principles and prevents the database engine from fully utilising an index.

What you can do is delimit your search value and also ensure the expression to search is correctly delimited; this is an unsargable expression however and the strorage engine will have to scan all rows every time -

```
declare @valueToFind varchar(10) = '4';

select *
from t 
where Concat(',', t.StringValue, ',') like Concat('%,' @valueToFind, ',%');
```

Answer (score 0):

for SQL Server 2016 and later you can use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or earlier version of SQL Server, there are many alternative, just do a search for it.

Or, you can simply do

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 where ',' + StringValue + ',' like '%,4,%'
```

Comment: But this `LIKE` won't match a value of `4,50` since the leading `4` doesn't have a comma before it ... comma-separated value lists are just a pain in the butt...... don't use those!